# Como chamar um relatório criado com iReport

Tags: ireport

Estou com a seguinte situação: recebi diversos relatórios criados por outro desenvolvedor, que utilizou o iReport. Ele me mandou os arquivos `.jasper` e `.jrxml`.

Eu tenho instalado o Eclipse Kepler com o plugin JasperSoft.

Como eu posso disparar os relatórios a partir de um `JFrame`, onde já tenho todos os botões para efetuar essas chamadas? Uso o MySQL como BD.

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda ou um exemplo?

Answer (score 4):

Augusto,

Tu pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
        Map parametros = new HashMap();
        String relatorio = "caminhodorelatorio\\arquivo.jasper";
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, parametros);            
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        view.setVisible(true);
```

Sendo necessários colocar os seguintes imports na tua classe:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
```

edit: a variável "parametros" é um parâmetro do tipo Map, que deve ser passado no método fillReport.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa variável tu pode adicionar valores para serem utilizados no relatório, como por exemplo: um título de relatório

```
parametros.put("ReportTitle", "PDF JasperReport");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas na linha JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, parametros) quais seriam os parâmetros a serem passados? Quem me enviou os relatórios disse que não há necessidade de passar nenhum parâmetro, pois os mesmos são informados quando são chamados quaisquer dos relatórios. É possível disparar sem passar parâmetros?

Comment: Editei a resposta original.

Comment: Ok, mas não estou encontrando esses .jars para impotar. Onde ficam essas bibliotecas quando é instalado o plugin no Eclipse?

Comment: Baixei o jar do Jasper e fiz os imports corretamente. Criei uma classe para teste e está gerando o seguinte erro: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory // O que pode estar acontecendo? Obrigado pelas ajudas !!!

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError é um erro muito comum.
Da uma olhada na explicação sobre ele: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Mas no teu caso, provavelmente é a falta destes jars no teu classpath!
Tem toda  explicação deste problema: http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-14396-CLASSPATH-E-PATH-PARA-O-IREPORT-E-JASPERREPORT.html